# Can't quite figure out this DRF endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on this endpoint to store an email. I send a POST to /emails with `{ "email": "user101c@email.com" }` and get an error `IntegrityError at /emails (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")`. Clearly, this is a database level error. The user_id field shouldn't be set by the user. I'm not sure how to proceed.

models.py

```py
class EmailAddress(ExportModelOperationsMixin('email_address'), models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='emails', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    verify_key = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    verification_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    reset_key = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=255, blank=True)
    reset_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("email")
        verbose_name_plural = _("emails")
        unique_together = [("user", "email")]
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.verify_key = get_random_string(length=32)
        if not self.id: # if new
            verify_email_signal.send(sender=self.__class__, email=self.email, key=self.verify_key)
            self.verification_sent = timezone.now()
        super(EmailAddress, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```py
class EmailAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = account_models.EmailAddress
        fields = ['user', 'email', 'verified', 'created', 'verification_sent', 'reset_sent']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'user']
```

views.py

```py
class EmailAddressViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailAddressSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return account_models.EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

urls.py

```py
email_list = views.EmailAddressViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
email_detail = views.EmailAddressViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})
urlpatterns = [
    path('emails/', email_list, name='email_list'), 
    path('emails/<int:pk>/', email_detail, name='email_detail'), 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by including the authenticated user in the view set

```py
class EmailAddressViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailAddressSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return account_models.EmailAddress.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```